# First Time Setup runs every time I click Play

Tags: steam, dota-2

Whenever I run Dota 2, Steam shows me this UAC dialog:
[image: UAC Steam Program Files (x86)\Steam\bin\steamservice.exe /installscript steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\runasadmin.vdf 570]

If I click **No**, the game launches. If I click **Yes**, I see the following and then the game launches.
[image: Performing First Time Setup | Installing (Step 1 of 1)]

It's just an annoyance, but how can I prevent this from happening?

I've tried reinstalling both Steam and the game.

Comment: Disable UAC.  Also I had the same issue with Dota 2 a while back - I just google searched it and came across a thread on the Steam forums.  Eventually it just boiled down to disabling UAC.

Comment: @Mkalafut Eh, that's not too inspiring. I kind of appreciate UAC.

Comment: Try this: right click on your dota from your library, go under update tab, uncheck enable steam cloud, go to general tab, click "Set launch options", type in "start" in the text.

Comment: @Mkalafut Thanks, tried it and still got the UAC dialog on the third try after clicking `Yes` and `No` on the first and second. But that's interesting that there are launch options. Never knew that.

Comment: No problem.  I'd recommend doing a quick google search for "Dota 2 runs first time setup every launch" or something along those lines.  I wish I had more info but this happened to me a long time ago.

Comment: Also, try running Steam and the game as an administrator.

Comment: You know you can take a screenshot without using a camera...

Comment: Did you try to check the game cache for bugs? Go to your DotA 2 and rightclick it -> properties -> local files -> verify integrity of game cache. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Keavon I'm not aware of a way to take a screenshot of the secure desktop.

Comment: @Louis Sorry, I didn't realize you normally aren't able to do that, although I did find [a guide](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/take-a-screenshot-of-the-windows-uac-prompt-with-a-registry-or-group-policy-edit/). I don't expect anyone to do follow that, though.

Comment: @Keavon Haha, yeah the VM one is clever, but a camera is definitely quicker ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Identify the "steam app" number (I think DOTA2 is 570)

Find the `installscript.vdf` file in the game's install folder. Open it with a text editor You will see lines like this:

{...} InstallScript"
{
"Run Process"
{
`"DirectX"` {...}

For every "run process" item like `DirectX` highlighted above, add a new `dword` parameter in the registry and set it to `1` in the proper registry node. For Dota2, the app node is:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\Steam\Apps\570

If you using a 32-bit OS, omit `Wow6432Node`.

You can examine sibling game nodes for more confirmation, but I think once it all runs, steam also adds a dword named "Installed" with a value of 1.

Rarely, an installscript.vdf has a typo (like "DircetX"). I think you need to copy the typo in the registry entry.

This file may be rewritten when steam updates a game. Clearing the contents is a temporary fix.

Comment: I wanted to try this first, to counter the downvote, but I simply don't have that noce (@Valve)

Comment: search for "steam". lists the registry entries: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9609-OBMP-2526

Comment: @Louis:  Running first time setup should *create* that node.  If you create it by hand (my DOTA2 install just has "directx" = 1) it will prevent the script from running.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to the directory where Dota 2 is installed in your Steam Library.
- Open installscript.vdf with Notepad or any other text editor
- Replace the contents with:

> ```
> "InstallScript"
> {
>
> }
> ```

- Save the file and close Notepad.
- Set installscript.vdf to be read only via the file's properties.

This way Steam should never bug you again.

Comment: I tried this, as well as deleting the file, but it gets recreated/repopulated when I click play. This is what it was/becomes: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10425957

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add an answer for the strange cases when someones encounters that first time setup problem and no solution they can find on the Web works.

**What to do** Uninstall the previous version of the appropriate Visual C++ Redistributable so that you game's specific redistributable can install and then tell the Steam client that it (the specific redist) finished correctly.

I have provided a full explanation on [Steam discussions](http://steamcommunity.com//app/228400/discussions/0/618457398960665114/).

**Summary of the explanation**

There are cases when the "First time setup" and consequently the UAC window are caused by (read carefully, because it's unbelievable to me) a *more recent* version of the Visual C++ redistributable... Yes, you read it correctly.

Suppose you have already installed a game that required a Visual C++ redistributable package (version 10.0.40219 in my case). In case a game that requires an **older** version (10.0.30319 in my case) of the package tries to perform its setup, the VC redist installer will **fail**.

Yes, it will fail instead of reporting a success like one (meaning "I") would think. The programmers of the VC redist packages apparently consider it a failure when trying to install x.y.z while x.y.t, with t > z, is already there.

In my case, the game wasn't Dota 2, it was Ace Combat Assault Horizon in its PC version. Setting values in the registry didn't help. Running Steam as admin didn't help either. Nothing did. Except uninstalling the more recent version of the redistributable package.

**Reinstall version 10.0.40219** of the distributable. Applications built with the latest version of Visual Studio 2010 SP1 require it.

- [Installer for 10.0.40219 (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13523)
- [Installer for 10.0.40219 (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

Finally, **run Windows update**. Your game may use a version 10.0.30319 redistributable that predates security fixes addressing it ([example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2542054)).

Answer (score -3):

Just remove this file.. it worked for me

[image]

then open `570_install.vdf` as text, then delete all text inside of it then paste this...

```
"InstallScript"
{

}
```

save it.. DONE !