# Fixing steam installs

Tags: steam, windows-7

I have this problem with *a lot* of games on Steam and was wondering if there is a general fix. What happens is I go to install a game, it asks for admin permission, does it's thing, installs and runs fine. Then next time I try to run, it pops up with an admin permission box and asks for permissions again. Now usually here, it doesn't actually matter whether I hit "OK" or "Cancel", the game still runs. The game was installed correctly, but Steam doesn't recognize it as such.

It's a minor annoyance, but I'd like to be able to get rid of it. I think one of the main culprits are the c++ redistributables and direct x redistrutables. If I go into the folder where the games are "installed" I can double click to run those installers again and it will tell me newer versions of those are already installed and thus skip installing the older version. However, I think this is what's tripping Steam up. Steam sees that as a failure to install (which it isn't).

Recent examples of games giving me this problem include Assassin's Creed 3 (which asks for admin rights twice(!) once for the game and once for uplay) and Mafia 2.

Edit: Should add, this is Windows 7 64-bit.

Edit 2: Searching around some more, this seems very similar (although I don't play DOTA 2):
[First Time Setup runs every time I click Play](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163764/first-time-setup-runs-every-time-i-click-play)

I could try hacking around in the registry, but I have a lot of games which do this and I can't believe there isn't an easier solution somewhere.

Comment: Can you please provide the full text of the "admin permission" pop-up that appears when you try to open a game you've already installed? The exact wording of this text would be very useful to help diagnose this problem.

Comment: Chances are extremely good it's not the game, but Window's UAC that's giving those popups.  Not really a whole lot you can do about that one.

Comment: @Zibbobz: It's the standard "Do you want to let the following program make changes to you computer" (or words to that effect. I'm at work right now so can't check it) asking for the admin password. Usually entering the password and clicking ok starts up the steam installing dialog briefly before normal service is resumed. Clicking cancel just starts normally. The games are installed, just Steam doesn't seem to think so.

Comment: @Frank: I don't think that's it. They are UAC prompts, but none of these games should need admin privileges (evidenced by the fact they run just fine if I deny them). The prompts are because Steam insists the install failed, when it didn't. They are asking for my admin password so they are requesting elevated permissions.

Comment: Simple way to find out: Disable UAC, try installing again.  If no errors, it's pretty easy to figure out something UAC was doing was causing the issue.

Comment: @Frank: It installed fine the first time, and I'm not disabling UAC because it's useful. This is a problem with Steam confusing warning from installers (like "a newer version is already installed") with actual errors. Steam is the one asking for elevated permissions, which is doesn't need. Letting Steam just grab elevated permissions without asking isn't a solution.

Comment: Is there an option like "Don't show this again" or "Change when these notifications appear" on the dialog box?

Comment: @Brian: No. These are requests for privilege elevation.

Comment: Are you running Steam as admin?

Comment: @Brian: No. I am not running Steam as admin.

Comment: Fixing Steam is impossible; we have no source code, nor any way to tell Steam its doing it wrong.  Disabling UAC is something you CAN do.  If you want a fix, there you go.  Everything else is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @Frank: That's not exactly true. We have the install script `installscript.vdf`, it ought to be fixable.

Comment: Do you have access to the same settings, save games etc when you start it with admin right and without? I'm asking because if it's an old game that was originally for Win98 or later, you need admin rights to write to the Program Files folder (as it may try to do) but if you don't then it creates a virtual copy in your user directory and uses that instead. EDIT: I just saw what games you're having trouble with so that's not it, but I'm leaving the comment for general information.

Comment: Please test by installing a game as the admin from the admin profile. See if it  asks then in the standard user profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it does seem that going through the installscript.vdf and looking for everything under `Run Process` and putting that in the registry seems to get rid of the prompt. For example, for Assassin's Creed III I have this:

```
"Run Process"
{
    "DXSetup"
    {
        "process 1"     "%INSTALLDIR%\\Support\\DirectX\\DXSETUP.exe"
        "command 1"     "/silent"
        "NoCleanUp"     "1"
    }
    "VCRedist"
    {
        "HasRunKey"     "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Valve\\Steam\\Apps\\208480"
        "process 1"     "%INSTALLDIR%\\Support\\VCRedist\\vcredist_x86.exe"
        "command 1"     "/q"
        "NoCleanUp"     "1"
    }
    "Punkbuster"
    {
        "process 1"     "%INSTALLDIR%\\Support\\Punkbuster\\pbsvc.exe"
        "command 1"     "/i --no-prompts --no-display --skip-tests --i-accept-the-pb-eula"
        "NoCleanUp"     "1"
    }
    "uplaylauncher"
    {
        "process 1"     "%INSTALLDIR%\\Support\\GameLauncher\\UplayInstaller.exe"
        "command 1"     "/S"
    }
    "kb971512_x86"
    {
        "Requirement_OS"
        {
            "OSType"        "Windows Vista"
            "Is64BitWindows"        "0"
        }
        "process 1"     "%WinDir%\\system32\\wusa.exe"
        "command 1"     "\"%INSTALLDIR%\\Support\\KB971512-x86.msu\" /quiet "
        "IgnoreExitCode"        "1"
    }
    "kb971512_x64"
    {
        "Requirement_OS"
        {
            "OSType"        "Windows Vista"
            "Is64BitWindows"        "1"
        }
        "process 1"     "%WinDir%\\system32\\wusa.exe"
        "command 1"     "\"%INSTALLDIR%\\Support\\KB971512-x64.msu\" /quiet /norestart "
    }
}
```

Adding each (`DXSetup`, `VCRedist`, ...) of those to the registry under `Computer\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\Steam\Apps\208480` as a DWORD with a value of 1 leaves me with only the UPlay prompt (which I think *is* a uplay problem and not a Steam problem). The whole process could probably be automated except that I don't see an easy way to find the number (`208480`) for the app. It's not contained in the install file itself, so I had to find it by searching for Assassin's Creed in the store.

If it has to be done manually like this, then it probably isn't worth the effort.